# Adding jQuery plugin to vBulletin forum

Tags: jquery, vbulletin

I have been using a plugin called  tabSlideOUt By William Paoli for a while on my own site. Now, I would like to add it to a vBulletin site I now run, and have hit a few difficulties.
I am aiming to have it on all pages of my forum.

The 'Contact' tab found [here](http://jimbotech.co.uk/) is what I am aiming for.

However, when adding it to my forum, I come accross the error, that the div, that I had hoped to be 'hidden' until clicked (like the plugin) vica versa; just displays as normal (no styling relevant to the script I have in place.)

The site I am trying to add it to is; [here](http://ownedthegame.com/forums/) it does say it's offline, but... Everything I have added shows. I have the jQuery API in the headinclude as well as the plugin script itself.

I have never been quite so stuck as for where to start.

(Script I am using as the "tab")

```
<!-- Begin TAB SlideOut-->
  <div class="post-new-thread">
        <a class="handle" href="#">EG</a>
        <h3>EG</h3>
        <p>EX</p><br />
        <p>EX</p><br />
        <p>EXJimbo</p>
    </div>
<!--End SlideOut-->
```

Thank you. ~Jimbo

Comment: You have your jQuery `<script>` after the plugin `<script>`.  That won't work, since the plugin can only initialize if jQuery is present.